# PHP filter through string

Tags: php, string, search, split, include

```
$string = "this is a string";

if ($string.split(" ").includes "is string") {
echo "Included";
}
```

I want to separate query by spaces, and see if string includes all separated parts.

And if anybody has the code for this question.

Comment: use `explode(' ', $string)`

Comment: provide expected output

Comment: The code example you have shown looks more like JavaScript, than PHP.

Comment: `explode`, and then use `in_array` twice to look for `is` and `string` among the resulting array elements ...?

Comment: @CBroe Could you please help supply the PHP on how, I am still a beginner at php.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? If you don't know how the mentioned functions work, please go read up on them in the manual.

Comment: @zimorok How do you use explode in an IF

Answer (score 0):

simple code will be like this

```
<?php

$string_var = ['is','string'];
$string_to_check = 'this is a string';

$to_check = explode(' ',$string_to_check);

print_r($to_check);

foreach($to_check as $string)
{
    if(in_array($string,$string_var))
    {
        echo "Found: ".$string."\n";
    }
}
```